# React DIV dynamic layout algorithm to create a box-in-box view

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, html, user-interface

I am trying to represent the following onto a web page. - that is a data model representation illustrating objects, attributes and  child objects in a parent child hierarchy.

[image]

I was thinking to create a generic React component that would be able to store a single data object, but then also have that same object accept child instances in a sort of dynamic mechanism.

The result would be a nested-box type view, which would show all elements and nested children.

- the child div, would need to have some sort of layout feature (much like the grid-layout features of popular UI frameworks (material-ui, Scemantic-ui, Zurb foundation)
  [image]

at the end, The "model"  would look something like this.

[image]

I dont even know where to start to build something like this. I am looking for some ideas to build a UI like this... the intention at a later stage would be to enable something like React-draggable to allow dragging of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For infinite tree structure rendering purposes, you might need to look at recursion usage in React. I found some resources for you:

- https://dev.to/baso53/recursive-rendering-in-react-building-a-universal-json-renderer-f59
- https://medium.com/@suraj.rajan/recursion-using-reactjs-components-3c871f99fb2f

Basically, you need to create a function in the class which returns an instance of your class.